# Selenium: Setting remote webdriver user agents for different browsers

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, user-agent

I am looking up to set user agent for different browser using remote driver in `Python`

I am in situation where I don't have Remote selenium setup to try out following
So I am asking in advance whether following snippet correct or not

I figured out following approaches on web

## 1. Firefox

```
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX.copy()
    capabilities['general.useragent.override'] = user_agent_string
    driver = Remote(command_executor=server_url, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Is above correct?

## 2. PHANTOMJS

```
    # Start Service Phantomjs
    # get service_url
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS.copy()
    capabilities['phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent'] = user_agent_string
    driver = Remote(command_executor=service_url, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Is above correct?

## 3. CHROME

```
    #Not sure about this
    capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
    capabilities['chrome.switches'] = ['--user-agent=' + user_agent_string]
    driver = Remote(command_executor=server_url, desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

if this does not work (as I found some issues with it on google)

then,

Is there any other way? such as using Chrome options? how to do it?

## 4. IE

```
   Does it support or any need ?
```

Additionally, Is it possible to change User agent after drive instance created (Dynamically)?

Answer (score 1):

As per the selenium documentation changing user agent is best supported in Firefox Driver using Firefox Profile.You can refer the below python code:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", "some UA string")
driver = webdriver.Remote(desired_capabilities=webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.FIREFOX, browser_profile=profile)
```

**Is it possible to change User agent after driver instance created (Dynamically)?**

For now the answer is **NO.**

> RemoteWebdriver updates the capabilities map only when the session is
>   starting.We can't modify it elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks I tried but it is not changing ; I verified with 
driver.execute_script("return navigator.userAgent;")

Comment: Hey Nikhil I tried the same code using java at my end and its working fine.I dont have selenium setup for python for now. I will try and update you.

Comment: I had to call `profile.update_preferences()` after `set_preference` to get this to work.

Comment: So we MUST change the profile to change the user agent string? the reason i'm asking is because i need to maintain the session to avoid having to log in for every single instance i create